# Problem connecting to Internet with Ethernet (169 IP address)

Tags: internet

I'm currently sharing my Internet connection with my laptop to my Raspberry Pi 3 via an Ethernet cable.  When I entered the `hostname -i` command in the terminal, an IP address starting with 169 is returned and pinging any website doesn't work.  From what I've read, this means that the computer wasn't able to talk to a DHCP server and the only way to fix this is to reboot the router.  Unfortunately, I'm currently at a university and have no way to reboot the router.

Is there any way to reconfigure the Internet settings so that it works?

Comment: Rebooting the router under most circumstances isn't the solution, but just another way to say "don't bother me, go away" or "I don't know".

Answer (score 2):

`169` is a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address).

If you have DIRECTLY connected to your PC **there is NO network** connection.
You can talk to the PC (and vice versa).

You **CAN** enable ICS which **SHOULD** provide an IP address, but this is a Windows question.